# Ограничение одновременных запросов http

Tags: ajax, http, curl, асинхронность

Делаю ajax запросы на сайт, нужно обработать одновременно 20-30 запросов, но происходит следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ajax запрашивает по 6 запросов.

Возможно как-то обойти эти ограничения или сделать с мин задержкой (1мс), или реализовать это curl'ом?

Comment: А на какой стороне вас интересует решение-то, на стороне браузера, на стороне кода сайта или на стороне сервера?

Comment: На стороне браузера

Comment: Может быть тебе стоит посмотреть в сторону СПА и асинхроности?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем-то, суть такова - все браузеры имеют определенное максимальное количество открытых соединений с одним хостом. Если верить этим ответам, то оно на 2015 год [было таково](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser):

```
Firefox 2:  2
Firefox 3+: 6
Opera 9.26: 4
Opera 12:   6
Safari 3:   4
Safari 5:   6
IE 7:       2
IE 8:       6
IE 10:      8
Chrome:     6
```

Соответственно, есть три варианта решения вопроса:

1. Если речь идет о решении на стороне пользователя, то есть браузера, то конечно же можно изменить эту настройку, в разных браузерах по-разному.
2. Если речь идет о решении на уровне сервера, то тут можно посоветовать либо делать запросы к разным хостам, то есть 6 идет на site1.com, 6 на site2.com и тд.
3. Если речь идет о решении на уровне кода, то я советовал бы сократить непомерное число запросов и делать их все одним махом, ну или максимум - шестью :)

К третьему варианту - вполне может быть, что можно написать некий прокси-код на стороне js, дабы он упаковывал все запросы в несколько и посылал их, потом обратно распаковывая, если нет возможности объединить все запросы напрямую.

Comment: Мне первое максимально подходит, как можно убрать ограничение в браузере и есть может какое-то ограничение в  windows?

Answer (score 1):

Браузер имеет ограничение на кол-во параллельных запросов к одному ресурсу (домену), в разных браузерах это значение варируется:

```
Firefox 2:  2
Firefox 3+: 6
Opera 9.26: 4
Opera 12:   6
Safari 3:   4
Safari 5:   6
IE 7:       2
IE 8:       6
IE 10:      8
Chrome:     6
```

Для того чтобы обойти это ограничение создают субдомены, которые будут ссылаться на один ip-адрес:

```
a.mysite.com
b.mysite.com
c.mysite.com
...
```

Браузер воспринимает их как совершено разные сайты. Для того чтобы создать свой субдомен, в настройках хостинга найдите раздел с настройками DNS и добавьте CNAME запись

[image: настройка CNAME-записи]

*(данное изображение может отличаться у вашего хостинг-провайдера)*

Также потребуется настроить виртуальные хосты на сервере, чтобы они все ссылались на 1 директорию. Обратитесь за помощью к вашему хостинг-провайдеру.

---

Отправка одновременно 30 http-запросов говорит о неправильной постановке задачи. Если вам нужно двустороннее общение клиент-сервер, то советую ознакомиться с протоколом [Websocket](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) - его уже поддерживают все браузеры. Если вам не подходят вебсокеты - то попробуйте долгоиграющие запросы [long polling](https://habrahabr.ru/post/128535/). Иначе вашему ресурсу грозить лавинообразный рост нагрузки.

Comment: Задача чу-чуть не стандартная, и нужна чисто для одного запуска. Всем спасибо за ответы.